# React FontAwesone "bell-on" isn't available

Tags: html, css, reactjs, webui, react-font-awesome

I am using [React font-awesome](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react), by importing the icons objects.

I want to add a notification icon.

[This](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7/icon/bell) is working good:

```
     import {faBell} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

....
                    <FontAwesomeIcon  icon={faBell}  />
```

But when I am trying to get the equivalent of [this (Bell-on)](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7/icon/bell-o)
I cannot import it, and when I'm looking on the package's library it doesn't appear there.

I have tried to change some methods of using the package, but nothing helped.

Am I missing something, maybe I need to add some property  for get this "on" view, or this font isn't available for ReactFontAwesome?

Comment: Correct behavior if you are using the free version of FA. As you can check [here](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons?d=gallery&p=2&q=bell) not all the icons are available for free

Comment: Thanks, I have solved it by   npm install --save @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons